# How do I perform this XPath query with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

In the following code I am using XPath to find all of the matching nodes using XPath, and appending the values to a StringBuilder.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (XmlNode node in this.Data.SelectNodes("ID/item[@id=200]/DAT[1]/line[position()>1]/data[1]/text()"))
{
    sb.Append(node.Value);
}
return sb.ToString();
```

How do I do the same thing, except using Linq to XML instead? Assume that in the new version, this.Data is an XElement object.

Comment: a simple LINQ 2 XML query will have several possible null reference exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query syntax would look something like this.

```
var nodes = from item in Data.Elements("item")
            where item.Attribute("id").Value == "200"
            let dat = item.Element("DAT")
            from line in dat.Elements("line").Skip(1)
            let data = line.Element("data")
            select data;

var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var node in nodes)
    sb.Append(node.Value);
```

... this would get rid of the possible nullref exceptions and would get rid of the `foreach` loop.

```
var nodes = from item in Data.Elements("item")
            let id = item.Attribute("id")
            where id != null && id.Value == "200"
            let dat = item.Element("DAT")
            where dat != null
            from line in dat.Elements("line").Skip(1)
            let data = line.Element("data")
            where data != null
            select data.Value;
return nodes.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, r) => sb.Append(r))
            .ToString();
```

Comment: There are several points in this query where you could get nullref exceptions... depending on how well structured your XML is.

Comment: ID was the root node, so I removed that line, then it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Matthew, can you explain a scenerio where that might happen?

Comment: If there was no `@id`, no `DAT` element, or no `data` element.

Comment: If you have generated XML that is back with something like XSD (or you just trust it will be structured correctly) you can skip the null checks.  The XPath will pretty much do this for you.

Comment: I do plan to validate the XML with a schema eventually, but I will need the null checks until then, so that was useful.

Comment: Pretty much any of the method names that are `singular` could return `null`.  ... just something to think about

Answer (score 1):

You can still use XPath with a XElement. You have to include the System.Xml.XPath namespace since its an extension method

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse("<xml></xml>");
var elements = xml.XPathSelectElements("ID/item[@id=200]/DAT[1]/line[position()>1]/data[1]/text()");
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre. I gave the answer to Matthew because that was what I was looking for, but I'm curious about this. Would you say there is an advantage of XPath vs Linq to XML, other than familiarity?

Comment: Beside helping against the null reference problem that Matthew commented about, not really. Linq-to-xml can help you do strong typed comparaison (where clause) and it is very good against "xml-injection" if that even exists :P

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that :

```
var query = 
    from id in this.Data.Elements("ID")                      // ID
    from item in id.Elements("item")                         // /item
    where item.Attribute("id").Value == "200"                // [@id=200]
    let dat in item.Elements("DAT").ElementAtOrDefault(1)    // /DAT[1]
    where dat != null                                        // (ensure there is an element at index 1)
    from line in dat.Elements("line").Skip(1)                // /line[position()>1]
    let data in line.Elements("data").ElementAtOrDefault(1)  // /data[1]
    where data != null                                       // (ensure there is an element at index 1)
    select data                                              // /text()

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(XElement data in query)
{
    sb.Append(data.Value);
}
return sb.ToString();
```

As you can see, it's not really more convenient than XPath, so you should probably keep using XPath (as explained in Pierre-Alain's answer)

Comment: the `[1]` in XPath is the first element in the set (It's 1's based instead of 0 based)  You could just use `.Element` as in my example.

Comment: oh, that's right... it's been a while since I last used XPath, I'm a bit rusty ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have created an open source helper library that let's you generate xpath expressions using Linq-esq expressions. Not sure if it is helpful in your context, but posting the link to the API

http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/how-to-create-xpath-using-linq